# ¿Cómo se puede cambiar el color del icono del calendario?

Tags: html, css, css3, date, input

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Quiero cambiar el color del icono del calendario**

En `HTML` uso la etiqueta `input:date` como se muestra abajo:

```
<input class="form__input" type="date" name="birthDate" id="birthDate" required>
```

En `CSS` tengo esto. Consigo cambiar el fondo, pero no el color del icono:

```
.form__input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    background-color: var(--text-white);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

**¿Es posible hacer eso?**

Comment: ¿Estás usando alguna librería o framework para tus estilos?

Comment: No. Es solo HTML, CSS y JS

Answer (score 0):

una solución es invertir los colores. en este caso de negro a blanco. Aquí un ejemplo.

```
.form__input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    filter: invert(1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 4px;
  }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Eres lo máximo. Me funciono